# Intranet Auto Login (mediawiki)

Tags: php, apache, authentication, mediawiki, autologin

I am working on a mediawiki page and it is an intranet-based website. One of the requirement was to have an intranet auto login.

I've found 2 extensions on mediawiki (LDAP extension and Auth_remoteuser extension) but I am not sure of which extension to implement the auto login.

Are both of the extension suitable for my enviroment setup as follows?

- PHP 5.3.3 (cgi/fcgi)
- MySQL 5.1.73
- Apache 2.1.6
- Mediawiki 1.22.0

Thanks for all responses and suggestion. I've been stuck for so long. I really appreciate some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What software do you use to implement the Ldap directory?

You can use both of the extensions you mentioned for your use case, but they has to be configured very differently.

[Auth_remoteuser](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Auth_remoteuser) uses the REMOTE_USER environment variable, which is set by the webserver after the user is authenticated successfully (so, in fact, you delegate the authentication to your webserver). Now you have to configure your apache to use NTLM/Ldap to authenticate your users.

[LdapAuthenticaton](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication), on the other hand, is shipped with an own auto-login module, but unfortunately i don't know, how it works and if it fits your needs. The setup is pretty simple, just follow [these steps](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LDAP_Authentication/Configuration_Options#Enabling_the_plugin). A full setup (specifically for IIS, but should work with Apache, too) can be found in [this support thread](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Extension_talk:LDAP_Authentication/Automatic_Logon_to_Mediawiki_Using_IIS).

Btw.: MediaWiki 1.22 isn't the actual stable release of MediaWiki. You should consider upgrading to the latest stable: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download (but be aware: LdapAuthentication isn't tested with 1.24 as far as i know, so you should test it by yourself before using it in production).

Comment: thanks for your response! I'm afraid I do not understand your question on which software do I use to implement the LDAP directory. I've already enabled LDAP support on my php.ini file. Is this not enough? Thanks for your advise! Appreciated it!!

Comment: Ldap is just a protocol, which has to be implemented in a software, usually called a Ldap server. Enabling ldap support in php isn't enough, you need a ldap directory. I think a good start would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol and your prefered search engine :)

Comment: thanks again for your response. I have looked at the wikipedia link u posted and can I check if the last section (ldap client) they mentioned are the same as ldap server? Which means I can just download of it? Also, is ldap server needed for both auth_remote / ldap extension for either iis /apache? Thanks Florian! I am really thankful for your advices!

Comment: Hi Florian, I would like to ask you some questions. I have use Auth_remoteuser extension and in my apache, I used the module mod_sspi for the single sign on. May I ask if this mod_sspi module allows sso for both apache2handler and cgi/fcgi ??

Thank You for your time and assistance! Hope to receive your reply!

Comment: Hi, sorry, but i haven't any  experience with this module. I think that someone will answer your question if someone knows the answer :)